# Send email using phpmailer on GoDaddy hosting

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a email using the GoDaddy but the problem is my code isn't working.

Do I need to configure something on GoDaddy? The idea is I have a customer and they have a gmail account. The site has a form and the customer needs to receive all the submitted contact information to their gmail account.

I have no idea how to do it and have tried for three days with no success.

This is the code that I'm using to send the emails to the account:

```
/* Instanciando as Bibliotecas Responsaveis pelo PHPMailer */
require_once '../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require_once '../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';


/* Instanciando a Classe de Email */
$email  = new PHPMailer();

/* Configurando o Email. */
$email->SMTPSecure   = "ssl";
$email->IsSMTP();
$email->SMTPAuth     = true;

$email->Host         = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
$email->Port         = 465;



$email->Username     = "email@example.com";
$email->Password     = "";
$email->IsHTML(true);


/* Configuracoes de quem Esta Mandando o Email. */
$email->SetFrom($_POST['txtEmail'], $_POST['txtName']);
$email->AddReplyTo($_POST['txtEmail'], $_POST['txtName']);
$email->From         = "email@example.com";
$email->FromName     = $_POST['txtName'];
$email->AddAddress('email@example.com');
$email->Subject      = 'Contact Us Email';
$email->Body         =  'Name : '           .$_POST['txtName'].             '<br/>'.
                        'Email : '          .$_POST['txtEmail'].            '<br/>'.
                        'Especialidade : '  .$_POST['txtEspecialidade'] .   '<br/>'.
                        'Phone : '          .$_POST['txtTelefone'].         '<br/>'.

                        'Message : '        .$_POST['txtComentario'];

/* Verificar se o Email foi Enviado com Sucesso */
if($email->Send()):
    $Mensagem = 'Email Enviado com Sucesso';
else:
    $Mensagem = 'Erro ao Enviar o Email '.$email->ErrorInfo;
endif;

/* Mostrar o Resultado. */
echo $Mensagem;
```

I'm sorry but it's in Portuguese. Thanks people.

Comment: Just FYI: you included your email address in the code. If you want to remove it, click edit and censor it. Then, 'flag' your question for moderator attention, so the email address can be removed from the old revision (otherwise it would be still accessible). **Welcome to StackOverflow** :)

Comment: Since this isn't that helpful I'm going to comment. Most times non-VPS hosting solutions deny incoming or outgoing SMTP ports to prevent spammers from setting up shop. Or just disable the usage of the mail/sendmail programs from being used. I would check with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 11):

GoDaddy has several limitations for its shared-hosting plans.

If you're trying to send emails from the GoDaddy host, you'll need to use the following SMTP server:

```
relay-hosting.secureserver.net
```

Also, keep in mind that the GoDaddy SMTP servers are very busy, which means it might take some time until your email sent to its recipient.

Don't waste your time and try to configure other SMTP servers (Gmail etc) to handle your outgoing emails. GoDaddy has blocked this option and limited it only to the mentioned server above.

Read here: [GoDaddy costumer service answer](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/trying-to-send-mail-through-smtp-port-is-not-allowing-for-external-services/)

Comment: Couldn't the OP use Gmail's settings for SMTP instead, since they will be using a Gmail address? That way it won't have to relay through GoDaddy's servers for outgoing mail.

Comment: @Fred-ii-It's impossible to use Gmail as SMTP from GoDaddy shared hosting.

Comment: Really? Gawd... you'd kind of figure you could. Oh well, scratch that one out.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried using relay-hosting.secureserver.net as the address, but after a lot of frustration I found that leaving "localhost" as the host and port 25 as the default port in my PHPMailer config, mail went through, and quickly at that. Yes, this is on a live, production website hosted by GoDaddy.

Comment: Just saw your comment - I recently talked to GoDaddy support and apparently their new servers (as of a few months ago) use these settings.