# Mandrill PHPMailer giving Error: SMTP Connect() failed

Tags: mandrill

When I am trying to send a mail using mandrill by this PHPMailer method it is showing an error as SMTP Connect() Failed. This is my code:

```
<?php         
    require 'class.phpmailer.php';     
    $mail = new PHPMailer;  
    $mail->IsSMTP();           
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                    
    $mail->Port = 587;                                      
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 
    $mail->Username = 'MANDRILL_USERNAME';                  
    $mail->Password = 'API_KEY';                     
    $mail->From = 'abc@xyz.com';   
    $mail->FromName = 'Your From name';   
    $mail->AddAddress('def@tuv.com');                
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                             
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';          
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>';    
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';    
    if(!$mail->Send()) {           
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';        
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;      
       exit;   
    }      
    echo 'Message has been sent';   
?>
```

I am not able to find the problem. I have also included the phpmailer files from which the class.phpmailer.php file is arrived at. Please help...

Answer (score 2):

An SMTP connection error is often because of a hosting provider or ISP blocking the port(s) you're using.  We have additional info in the Mandrill KB about this with troubleshooting steps: [Why am I getting a "Relay Access Denied" error trying to send through SMTP?](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24633717-Why-am-I-getting-a-Relay-Access-Denied-error-trying-to-send-through-SMTP-)

Answer (score 2):

:(
[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18858629/1427338)

> GoDaddy has several limitations for its shared-hosting plans.
>
> If you're trying to send emails from the GoDaddy host, you'll need to
>   use the following SMTP server:
>
> relay-hosting.secureserver.net Also, keep in mind that the GoDaddy
>   SMTP servers are very busy, which means it might take some time until
>   your email sent to its recipient.
>
> Don't waste your time and try to configure other SMTP servers (Gmail
>   etc) to handle your outgoing emails. GoDaddy has blocked this option
>   and limited it only to the mentioned server above.
>
> Read here: [GoDaddy costumer service answer](http://support.godaddy.com/help/topic/58/web-hosting/forum/topic/trying-to-send-mail-through-smtp-port-is-not-allowing-for-external-services/)

If the link is still working ... lucky you.