# Mandrill ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mandrillapp.com

Tags: mandrill

I am not trying to do anything fancy. I am just trying to send an email using API of mandrill. I have included the library but I still get the error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.mandrillapp.com [Connection refused #111]' in /home/laundryanna/public_html/mandrill/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:265 Stack trace: #0 /home/laundryanna/public_html/mandrill/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php(62): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1 /home/laundryanna/public_html/mandrill/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(113): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 /home/laundryanna/public_html/mandrill/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(79): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 /home/laundryanna/public_html/mandrill/mailed.php(26): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array) #4 {main} thrown in /home/laundryanna/public_html/mandrill/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 265". Here is the code:

```
<?php

include_once "lib/swift_required.php";

$subject = 'Hello from Mandrill, PHP!';
$from = array('mail1@example.com' =>'EA CEO');
$to = array(
 'email1@gmail.com'  => '$_POST["e1"]',
 'email1' => 'Recipient2 Name'
);

$text = "Mandrill speaks plaintext";
$html = "<em>Mandrill speaks <strong>HTML</strong></em>";

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587);
$transport->setUsername('***ore@gmail.com');
$transport->setPassword('******');
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$message->setTo($to);
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
{
 echo 'Message successfully sent!';
} else {
 echo "There was an error:\n";
 print_r($failures);
}

?>
```

Please tell me what to do... :(

Comment: Check if You can connect to smtp.mandrillapp.com 587 port at all (`telnet smtp.mandrillapp.com 587`).

Comment: I got 220 smtp.mandrillapp.com ESTMP

Comment: Response indicates I can connect .

Comment: The next thing would be to `tcpdump` all traffic to/from smtp.mandrillapp.com:587 to see what error is actually returned when You script is connecting.

Comment: Dude I was using godaddy server. I think they have made some restrictions on smtp server as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18858629/4224275

Comment: I checked it in my localhost and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: I tried another server same issue. Is there any setting that we need to change in hosting?

Comment: Please provide SMTP session transcript (what requests/responses are transfered on the wire). Without it it is only guessing.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what it was?