# Codeigniter PHPMailer email not sending to office 365 account

Tags: codeigniter, email, phpmailer, office365

i am using php mailer in Codeigniter. 
here is my email settings
mail was sending to other email id but not sending to email id which is in office 365.

```
 <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed.');

$config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';              // Mail engine switcher: 'CodeIgniter' or 'PHPMailer'
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';                   // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.office365.com';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'example@example.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'password';
//$config['smtp_port']        = 587;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 5;                        // (in seconds)
$config['smtp_crypto']      = 'tls';                       // '' or 'tls' or 'ssl'
$config['smtp_debug']       = 4;                        // PHPMailer's SMTP debug info level: 0 = off, 1 = commands, 2 = commands and data, 3 = as 2 plus connection status, 4 = low level data output.
$config['wordwrap']         = true;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';                   // 'text' or 'html'
$config['charset']          = 'ISO-8859-15';                     // 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15', ...; NULL (preferable) means config_item('charset'), i.e. the character set of the site.
$config['validate']         = true;
$config['priority']         = 3;                        // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; on PHPMailer useragent NULL is a possible option, it means that X-priority header is not set at all, see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/449
$config['crlf']             = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['newline']          = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = false;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
$config['encoding']         = '8bit';                   // The body encoding. For CodeIgniter: '8bit' or '7bit'. For PHPMailer: '8bit', '7bit', 'binary', 'base64', or 'quoted-printable'.
```

i have the following error

```
  Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:25, timeout=5, options=array ( ) 2016-01-02 10:00:49 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2016-01-02 10:00:49 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting bool(false)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

**same setting are working in other servers, but not working in Go daddy server.
i checked openssl connection was enabled.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email using phpmailer on GoDaddy hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858400/send-email-using-phpmailer-on-godaddy-hosting)

Answer (score 0):

There are many duplicates of this question, and it's also covered in the PHPMailer docs: GoDaddy blocks outbound email, so you have to use their mail servers.